# how to filter a component after it's been mapped?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map, array-filter

I'm looking to filter my array of jokeComponents to give me back an array of jokes that are less than x number of characters.

```
    const jokeComponents = jokesData.map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)
    
    return (
        <div>
            {jokeComponents}            
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to then run the filter method on the jokeComponents, but it returned an empty array.
Where should I run this filter method?

if I do it directly on the jokesData like so,

```
const jokeComponents = jokesData.filter(joke => joke.length < 100)
```

I am not able to return the  component.

do I specify it to my  component that it needs to be less than x number of characters that I want returned? Do I need to run this filter method inside my  component's prop? (I tried, but it gave me an error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const jokeComponents = jokesData
    .filter(joke => joke.punchLine.length < 100)
    .map(joke => (<Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />))
```

Comment: this worked. I think since one of the jokes in my jokes json data is undefined (not listed), filtering out joke.question gave me error: question is undefined. 
thank you!

Comment: extra question: is it possible to run a filter function within the map method?

Comment: The map method returns exactly one element per input element, so you cannot filter per se. However, you can return a null element from within the map: ```...map(x => { if(...) return null; else return (<Joke ... />); })```

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of doing this:
For all of these you need to use jokesData as a state variable:

```
const [jokesData, setJokesData] = React.useState(null)
```

1. Conditional rendering:

```
    return(
      jokesData.map(joke => {
        joke.length < 100 ? <Joke ... /> : null
      })
    )
```

2. Updating jokesData array with a function (perhaps a click)

```
      const updateJokes = () => {
        setJokesData(jokesData.filter(joke => joke.length<100))
      }
```

3. Usin useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setJokesData(jokesData.filter(joke => joke.length < 100))
  }, [jokesData, setJokesData])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this :

```
    const jokeComponents = jokesData
                          .filter(item =>item.length <100)
                          .map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)

return (
    <div>
        {jokeComponents}            
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: yes! I think I also need to specify item.question or item.punchLine in order for it to filter out what I want. and as mentioned in another comment below, since I one of the jokes in my json data doesn't have a question (undefined), it gave me an error when I tried to filter out the item.question (or joke.question). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set condition while you are mapping, you can add index as a second parameter to map(), so your code will be similar to the following code:

```
const jokeComponents = jokesData.map((joke,index) => index<100 && <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)

return (
    <div>
        {jokeComponents}            
    </div>
)
```

}